# How do I set up an Ubuntu FTP server?

Tags: 12.04, server, networking, ftp

I am very new at this, and I need help setting up an FTP server that I can connect to outside of my network. I have Ubuntu Server 12.04 installed, as well as Webmin, and Vsftpd. I just need help figuring out how to connect to my server and use it as a FTP Server.

Comment: If possible, you should consider using ssh instead.  But either way, you will need to open up the port that you are using in your router.  I think the default is 21, but you can change it in the configuration file; look for something like `listen_port=nnnn`, where nnnn is the port.

Comment: Does the ftp server already work, but the problem is that you cannot access it outside your network? If you connect to the Internet through a router, have you configured the ftp server to allow passive mode connecctions, and forwarded ports for those connections as well as for port 21 (or whatever you're using for the control connection)? I recommend **editing your question** to provide this information. (Unless that enables you to solve your problem--then just post an answer saying what specifically solved it, and this comment can subsequently be removed as obsolete.)

Answer (score 1):

If your server has SSH installed you can easily use sftp to it. I use FileZilla from Windows machines to connect to any server using sftp with port 22. Just use your username and password as if SSH.

Comment: This specifically requires that an SSH *sever*, such as `openssh-server`, be installed on the server. You might want to expand your answer to include more information about this. If you know how, you might also want to include information about setting up an ftp server in case the OP prefers that to SSH (since that's what the OP said he wants to do).